# close() or join() equivalent for celery jobs (python)?

Tags: python, celery

I [recently learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885227/persistent-processes-post-python-pool) that the multiprocessing package `Pool` with python requires you to call:

```
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

when you're finished in order to free the memory used for state in those processes. Otherwise, they persist and your computer will fill up with python jobs; they won't use the CPU, but will hog memory.

My question is this:
I'm now using `celery` for parallelization (instead of `Pool`-- I'm in operating within a Django WSGI app, and `Pool` makes it difficult to prevent all users from forking jobs at once, which will crash the server).

I've noticed a very similar phenomenon with `celery`: my 6 celery processes running in the background start to gobble up memory. Is this normal or is there the equivalent of calling close() and join() that I can use to tell a `celery` task that I've retrieved the result and don't need it anymore?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referring to documentation there's no need to close workers as they will be closed automatically. But you can force close them using [kill](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker) or discard them:

```
from celery.task.control import discard_all
discard_all()
```

Here are some [examples](https://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master/examples/eventlet) from developers.